# Associative Arrays

Tags: php, mysql

I'm needing to rearrange Array 1 by the order of how the [id] (oper-%%%%%%%%%%) appears within Array 2, and I'm not quite sure as to how to approach this.

Array 1

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => oper-4c597644-402490ee [amount] => 17498.5 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => oper-4f30019a-27f27473 [amount] => 10383.5 ) [2] => Array ( [id] => oper-4bceffd1-21e0af5b [amount] => 6277 ) [3] => Array ( [id] => oper-4f300d33-de9592e3 [amount] => 11382 ) [4] => Array ( [id] => oper-4c236420-0b11e945 [amount] => 14759 ) [5] => Array ( [id] => oper-50f6e4ad-9effbec7 [amount] => 3058 ) [6] => Array ( [id] => oper-4f05a90b-03b379f9 [amount] => 12112.5 ) [7] => Array ( [id] => oper-qtgjvw8y-1uqtw058 [amount] => 10023 ) [8] => Array ( [id] => oper-52657816-3d6516e2 [amount] => 3495 ) )
```

Array 2

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Bob [1] => oper-4bceffd1-21e0af5b ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Bob [1] => oper-4c236420-0b11e945 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => Bob [1] => oper-4c597644-402490ee ) [3] => Array ( [0] => Bob [1] => oper-4f05a90b-03b379f9 ) [4] => Array ( [0] => Bob [1] => oper-4f30019a-27f27473 ) [5] => Array ( [0] => Bob [1] => oper-4f300d33-de9592e3 ) [6] => Array ( [0] => Bob [1] => oper-50f6e4ad-9effbec7 ) [7] => Array ( [0] => Bob [1] => oper-52657816-3d6516e2 ) [8] => Array ( [0] => Bob [1] => oper-qtgjvw8y-1uqtw058 ) [9] => Array ( [0] => Empty [1] => ) [10] => Array ( [0] => Upg. [1] => ) [11] => Array ( [0] => Ren. [1] => ) )
```

Bob is just an example "name" 
Here is my code so far (And I know this isn't clean because this isn't done with PDO, I'm just trying to get this to work at the moment):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblOperatorGoals WHERE MonthlyGoal LIKE '$currentDate%'");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $opernameArray[] = $row['OperatorName'];
  $operIDArray[] = $row['OperatorID'];
  $monthlyGoal[] = substr($row['MonthlyGoal'], 8);
  $operArray[] = array('name' => $row['OperatorName'], 'id' => $row['OperatorID']);
}

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblUserPayments WHERE ChargeAmount IS NOT NULL AND  PaymentStatus='OK' AND PaymentDate LIKE '$currentDate%'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $operearnedArray[] = array(
      'amount' => $row['ChargeAmount'], 
      'id' => $row['OperatorID']);
}

foreach ($operearnedArray as $value) {
  if($value['id'] == '' || $value['id'] == null) {
    continue;
  }
  if(array_key_exists($value['id'], $operSums1)) {
    $operSums1[$value['id']] += $value['amount'];
  } else {
    $operSums1[$value['id']] = $value['amount'];
  }
}

foreach ($operSums1 as $id => $value) {
  if (in_array($id,$operIDArray)) {
    $operSums[] = array(
    'id' => $id,
    'amount' => $value);
  }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Associative arrays are just not my cup of tea.

Basically I'm looking for an Array that looks like this:

```
Array ( [name] => Bob [id] => oper-%%%%%%%%%%%%%% [amount] => $$$$$$$$$$$ )...ect...ect...
```

Answer (score 0):

Crude but should work:

```
$toSort = array(
    array ('id' => 'oper-4c597644-402490ee', 'amount' => 17498.5,),
    array ('id' => 'oper-4f30019a-27f27473', 'amount' => 10383.5,),
    array ('id' => 'oper-4bceffd1-21e0af5b', 'amount' => 6277,),
    array ('id' => 'oper-4f300d33-de9592e3', 'amount' => 11382,),
    array ('id' => 'oper-4c236420-0b11e945', 'amount' => 14759,),
    array ('id' => 'oper-50f6e4ad-9effbec7', 'amount' => 3058,),
    array ('id' => 'oper-4f05a90b-03b379f9', 'amount' => 12112.5,),
    array ('id' => 'oper-qtgjvw8y-1uqtw058', 'amount' => 10023,),
    array ('id' => 'oper-52657816-3d6516e2', 'amount' => 3495,),
);

$assigned = array (
    array ('Bob','oper-4bceffd1-21e0af5b'),
    array ('Bob','oper-4c236420-0b11e945'),
    array ('Bob','oper-4c597644-402490ee'),
    array ('Bob','oper-4f05a90b-03b379f9'),
    array ('Bob','oper-4f30019a-27f27473'),
    array ('Bob','oper-4f300d33-de9592e3'),
    array ('Bob','oper-50f6e4ad-9effbec7'),
    array ('Bob','oper-52657816-3d6516e2'),
    array ('Bob','oper-qtgjvw8y-1uqtw058'),
);

$sorted = assignData($toSort, $assigned);

var_dump($sorted);

function assignData($raw, $order)
{
    $returnArray = array();
    foreach($order as $entry):
        foreach($raw as $rawEntry):
            if ($rawEntry['id'] == $entry[1]):
                $temp = array(
                    'name' => $entry[0],
                    'oper' => $rawEntry['id'],
                    'amount' => $rawEntry['amount'],
                );
                $returnArray[] = $temp;
            endif;
        endforeach;
    endforeach;
    return $returnArray;
}
```

Comment: I've edited my post, I still can't seem to get it to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<?php

$data = [
    ['id' => 'oper-4c597644-402490ee', 'amount' => 17498.5],
    ['id' => 'oper-4f30019a-27f27473', 'amount' => 10383.5],
    ['id' => 'oper-4bceffd1-21e0af5b', 'amount' => 6277],
    ['id' => 'oper-4f300d33-de9592e3', 'amount' => 11382],
    ['id' => 'oper-4c236420-0b11e945', 'amount' => 14759],
    ['id' => 'oper-50f6e4ad-9effbec7', 'amount' => 3058],
    ['id' => 'oper-4f05a90b-03b379f9', 'amount' => 12112.5],
    ['id' => 'oper-qtgjvw8y-1uqtw058', 'amount' => 10023],
    ['id' => 'oper-52657816-3d6516e2', 'amount' => 3495]
];

$names = [
    ['BobA', 'oper-4bceffd1-21e0af5b'],
    ['BobB', 'oper-4c236420-0b11e945'],
    ['BobC', 'oper-4c597644-402490ee'],
    ['BobD', 'oper-4f05a90b-03b379f9'],
    ['BobE', 'oper-4f30019a-27f27473'],
    ['BobF', 'oper-4f300d33-de9592e3'],
    ['BobG', 'oper-50f6e4ad-9effbec7'],
    ['BobH', 'oper-52657816-3d6516e2'],
    ['BobI', 'oper-qtgjvw8y-1uqtw058'],
    ['Empty', ''],
    ['Upg.', ''],
    ['Ren.', '']
];

$idMappedNames = array_column($names, 0, 1);

$summary = array_reduce($data, function($carry, $item) use(&$idMappedNames) {
    if (!array_key_exists($item['id'], $carry)) {
        $carry[$item['id']] = [
            'name' => $idMappedNames[$item['id']],
            'amount' => 0
        ];
    }

    $carry[$item['id']]['amount'] += $item['amount'];

    return $carry;
}, []);
```

Comment: I just edited my post, I still can't seem to get it to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect these information it in just single SQL Query

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT a.*,u.OperatorName,u.MonthlyGoal
   FROM tblUserPayments a LEFT JOIN tblOperatorGoals u ON a.OperatorID = u.OperatorID
   WHERE a.ChargeAmount IS NOT NULL 
   AND a.PaymentStatus='OK' 
   AND a.PaymentDate LIKE '$currentDate%' 
   AND u.MonthlyGoal LIKE '$currentDate%' " );
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $wantedArray[] = array(
      'OperatorName' => $row['OperatorName'], 
      'MonthlyGoal'=>$row['MonthlyGoal'],
      'ChargeAmount' => $row['ChargeAmount'], 
      'OperatorID' => $row['OperatorID']);
}
```

---

But as the question originally asked goes:

```
$desiredArray = array();
$id_to_amount = array();
foreach($array1 as $x)
   $id_to_amount[$x['id']] = $x['amount'];
foreach($array2 as $x)
{
   $id = $x[1];
   $name = $x[0];
   $amount = -1;
   if(isset($id_to_amount[$id]))
      $amount = $id_to_amount[$id];
   $desiredArray[] = array('id'=>$id,'name'=>$name,'amount'=>$amount );
}
```

Comment: I just edited my post to include an additional table that I need to pull information.

Comment: The operator name is pulled from tblOperatorGoals. Sorry I left that out.

Comment: @Juan ok, I eddited my joined tables solution with tblOperatorGoals table and MonthlyGoal field

Comment: I appreciate all your help. The only thing is 'ChargeAmount' is located in table 'tblUserPayments', so I have to use both 'tblOperatorGoals' and 'tblUserPayments' to pull the necessary information. I'm not worried about including the 'MonthlyGoal' variable.

Comment: Yes, and that is why you are joining them together. To have all needed info in one place, instead of two places that you need to additionally merge later. Joining two SQL tables creates one (virtual) with data of both of them.

Comment: Thank you again for your help! I'm now getting a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''ChargeAmount'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ')'

Comment: Forgot a comma on previous line. Corrected.

Comment: That worked perfectly, but now I'm trying to use the foreach loops that I was using to get a total of all amounts for each operator. As in Array ( [name] => Bob [id] => oper-%%%%%%%%%%%%%% [amount] => $$$$$$$$$$$ ), where [amount] is the total of all amounts for each operator.

Comment: Hey, SQL can do even that for you: http://pastebin.com/fmxrSkck That will output OperatorID,OperatorName,MonthlyGoal, and MonthlyAmountSum (calculated as total sum of all amounts for that operator)